# How to create list of TargetDescription in CloudFormation from list of EC2 instance ids?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

Is there any native way to create a list of TargetDescriptions to add to a load balancer TargetGroup based on a list of EC2 instance ids passed as parameters to the template? I know there are template preprocessors or frameworks like Troposphere that let you add code on top of your template but I would like to know of a native way to solve this specific problem.

My code at the moment looks like this:

```
TargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Port: 8020
      Protocol: HTTP
      VpcId: !Ref VPCId
      TargetType: instance
      Targets:
        - Id: !Ref EC2InstanceOne
          Port: 8020
        - Id: !Ref EC2InstanceTwo
          Port: 8020
```